# Some users get 503, some dont

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

My site is here: [lemonfinity.com/extra/portfolio/quotemachine.html](http://lemonfinity.com/extra/portfolio/quotemachine.html)

Some people are having a completely smooth experience with no errors, but some are just getting a repeating 503 status error.

I'm using Yahoo's YQL service and I don't understand why it works for some and doesn't for others. I'm not sure if it's a yahoo error or the site I'm reading from: BrainyQuote.

My query is similar to the following:

```
select content from html where url='http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/w/George_Washington.html' and xpath='//div/div/span/a'
```

[Here's the console with the working query](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+content+from+html+where+url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brainyquote.com%2Fquotes%2Fauthors%2Fw%2FGeorge_Washington.html'+and+xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%2Fspan%2Fa')

Comment: And some users are getting a "Quelle tragédie!"
404: page does not exist

Comment: @popovitsj haha sorry, fixed it!